# Get an object "FragmentManager" in "Service"

Tags: java, android, service

Is it possible to get an object "FragmentManager" in "Service"? Is it possible to pass an object "FragmentManager" from "Activity" in the "Service".

PS: Includes not officially supported features.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is it possible to get an object "FragmentManager" in "Service"?

No, sorry.

> Is it possible to pass an object "FragmentManager" from "Activity" in the "Service".

That would be an exceptionally bad idea.

If you wish for your service to update your UI, bear in mind that *there might not be a UI*. The user is welcome to press their BACK or HOME button to exit your UI, even while your service is running.

Also bear in mind that it might be a *different UI*. For example, when the user rotates the device from portrait to landscape, your activity (and fragments, by default) will be destroyed and recreated. Or, the user may tap on something that brings a different activity to the foreground, and that activity has its own fragments and manager.

Therefore, to have your service update your UI, you need to use a communications path that supports this sort of decoupled operation, such as:

- send a broadcast
- send a broadcast using `LocalBroadcastManager`
- update content via a `ContentProvider`, with activities using `CursorLoader` or `ContentObserver` to be notified about data changes
- etc.

Comment: That is, even if I will be able to transfer FragmentManager to servise. It (FragmentManager) will become invalid (for the activity from which it was obtained) when the user rotates the device? Right?

Comment: @K.G.V.: "It (FragmentManager) will become invalid (for the activity from which it was obtained) when the user rotates the device?" -- possibly. I have not looked at the underlying implementation to see whether the manager itself is retained across configuration changes. Different activities (e.g., Activity A vs. Activity B) definitely have different `FragmentManager` instances.

Comment: Try using LocalBroadcastManager. But a new problem: if my Activity is not active, then it can be removed from the cache. And then it will cease to receive messages. Is it possible to set a flag so that Activity was not removed from the cache?

Comment: @K.G.V.: If the user presses BACK, your activity is destroyed, and there is nothing to receive the messages. If you create a new instance of that activity (such as based on user input), it will need to query your database or whatever to get the current state. In any other circumstance (such as the user pressing HOME), your activity will still be around. "Is it possible to set a flag so that Activity was not removed from the cache?" -- no, no more than you can set a flag in your Web app to prevent a user from switching to another page in her Web browser.